# BluePrism-Unable to create database while i am on Client machine

Tags: sql-server, blueprism

I am on client network and installed Sql Server Express 2014, Blueprism 6 in win 10.

I am not able to create database after configuring in sql server configuraiton manager.

in my personal laptop, i am able to create DB if we setup "SQL server(SQLEXPRESS)"and  "SQL Server browser" in Configuration manager as local system and start running. But same setup is not working in Client networks.

Do we have any other setup for client networks.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Error- Failed to create database - CREATE DATABASE Permission denied in database master At Stage 'initializing

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is quite self-explanatory. When you install SQL server on your machine, you are automatically assigned as the server's `sysadmin`.

When you installed the server on the client network, you most likely installed it under a different account than the one you are using now. That account has the `sysadmin` role and can do anything, other accounts will have no access.

To fix this you need to log to that server (using Management Studio) and modify the authentication settings and/or add a new user with greater privileges.